# Trouble getting nginx to serve 'media' files

Tags: django, web, nginx, uwsgi

I've been working through a turotial and got stuck at this specific part and can't seem to figure it out. [This is exactly where I am stuck](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#basic-nginx-test).

Here is my mysite_nginx.conf

```
# mysite_nginx.conf
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on

    root / ;

    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name .81.*.*.*; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media      

    location /media/ {
        root /home/mysite/mysite1/blog/media; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }
    # Django static
    location /static/ {
        #alias /home/mysite/mysite1/blog/templates;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        root /home/mysite/mysite1/blog/static;
    }



    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/mysite/mysite1/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Here is the file structure of mysite [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rrnqSh2y) - Sorry for it being a total mess. I am aware of redundant static files. If you need any other files, I am happy to provide. Thank you.

Comment: Did you set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings?

Comment: @Selcuk when I visit the url: http://81.*.*.*:8000/media/image.png, I don't get anything. But I know nginx is running because when I visit http://81.*.*.* , I get the "welcome to nginx" page.

Comment: @Mikeec3 I'm going to look into this when I get back home today. Thanks for your response. I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: @Mikeec3 I looked and I did not have those configured in my settings,py, but upon adding this in, It still is not working.